# Purpose of adding ssh identity file to ssh agent and keychain

Tags: linux, ssh, git, ssh-keys, ssh-agent

I noticed that the Github instructions for adding an ssh key to your account say that you need to add the key to both your `~/.ssh/config` file AND to the `ssh agent` with `ssh-add`

https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent
[image]
[image]

But, I just noticed however that if I clear the keys from the ssh agent with `ssh-add -D`, then I'm still able to push and pull from my github repos just fine.
I think this makes sense because in my `~/.ssh/config` file, I specify that for `Host *` (all hosts), the exact IdentityFile to use, so it will use that one automatically.

So, my question is - why even add the key to the ssh-agent directly at all? Is there a case in which my way of only added to the ~/.ssh/config file won't work?

Comment: I **hope** you set a passphrase on that identity-file? If you didn't you probably won't notice a difference; if you did, adding it to the agent will allow you to enter the passphrase *ONCE* for the life-time of the running agent (or till you clear the identity). W/o the agent I'd expect you to be prompted for every connection attempt.

Comment: Yeah that's what I ended up realizing was the difference. Makes sense, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I **hope** you set a passphrase on that identity-file?

If you didn't you probably won't notice a difference; if you did, adding it to the agent will allow you to enter the passphrase *ONCE* for the life-time of the running agent (or till you clear the identity).

W/o the agent I'd expect you to be prompted for every connection attempt.

Comment: But what exactly is the difference between adding agent using `ssh-add` vs the config file? Because even if you deleted the config file, as long as the ssh agent is added it will still work and won't ask you for passphrase. Does it mean that if you did not add ssh agent via `ssh-add` and you only have config file, the passphrase will still be asked for every session?